# Como tratar exceção que nao pode deletar pois é uma foreign key

Tags: codeigniter, exceção, try-catch

não estou conseguindo tratar uma exceção que acontece quando vou deletar um endereço que esta sendo utilizado em outra tabela. estou usando o codeigniter

meu codigo é:

```
public function delete_endereco($cod_clientes_endereco){
    try{
        $acao = $this->db->delete('clientes_enderecos', array('cod_clientes_endereco' => $cod_clientes_endereco));
    }
    catch (SqlException $ex) {
        SqlException::throwDeleteException($ex);
    }
    if($acao){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Endereço deletado com sucesso!');
    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Este endereço não pode ser deletado, pois existe um pedido utilizando ele.');
    }
    redirect("pagina_cliente?page=enderecos");
}
```

Fica aparecendo o seguinte erro:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1451

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`pedidos`, CONSTRAINT `fk_pedidos_clientes_enderecos1` FOREIGN KEY (`endereco_cobranca`) REFERENCES `clientes_enderecos` (`cod_clientes_endereco`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTIO)

DELETE FROM `clientes_enderecos` WHERE `cod_clientes_endereco` = '5'

Filename: controllers/Pagina_cliente.php

Line Number: 160
```

Comment: Não consegue significa o que exatamente?

Comment: @rray em vez de capturar a exceção para mim poder tratar exibindo uma msg de erro, fica aparecendo: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Erro e exception php são duas coisas diferentes, nesse casso é so remover o try-catch, deixe o if resolver isso.

Comment: @rray ja tentei retirar o try-catch, mas fica aparendo a mesma tela com o erro.

Comment: Esse tipo erro aparecer não tem problema em ambiente de homologação, no ambiente de produção eles serão ocultados, claro vc deve tratar e fazer log deles.

Answer (score 1):

Oi.
Isso acontece porque o codeigniter não lança uma exceção nesse caso.

O que você pode fazer é:

Abra o arquivo database.php, ache a linha 
`$db['default']['db_debug']` e sete a pra `FALSE`.

E no seu código você pode manter o seguinte if:

`if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1451)`

caso você precise que algo especial aconteça no caso do erro ser lançado pelo db. Acredito que isso deve funcionar.

Comment: coloquei como sugerido, mas agora aparece o seguinte erro:
Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_error_number()

Comment: Pode verificar se o `$query_builder` está ativado no seu database.php?

Comment: sim está $query_builder = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema eu criei uma coluna na minha tabela de endereços chamada "ativo", e então ao invés de fazer a operação de delete no endereço, eu apenas atualizo a coluna de "ativo" para zero.

e na listagem de todos os endereços para o usuário ver, eu apenas listo os endereços que tem a coluna "ativo" igual a 1.

Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar...